# How to transfer value from one fragment to another

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have been trying to retrieve a value from a viewpager fragment but I can't seem to get it right.

The FragmentA consist of a listview, and when an item is clicked it should send the position as an int to FragmentB which suppose to display it in as a toast. Other code are working perfectly but the toast is not displaying anything.

Fragment A:

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                //This check whether the song is playing
                if (MusicPlaying.mp.isPlaying()) {
                    post = position;
                    MusicPlaying.mp.stop();
                    start();
                } else {
                    start();
                }

            }

        });

 public void start() {
        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.slide);
        vp.setCurrentItem(vp.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
    }

public static int rInt(){
        return post;
    }
```

FragmentB

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment{

    int position;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.album, container, false);
        position = ListMusic.rInt();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return v;
    }


}
```

Comment: You could try to look into a library called EventBus for the process of transferring data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct Communication between two fragments should be avoided whenever possible, but it should be done with the help of an Activity that is holding the two fragments , in your case, it is the activity in which view pager is inflated. I think you are trying to implement a master-detail layout in android, in which, if you do something in master fragment(your Listview fragment A) then it should pass data into detail fragment(your fragment B) . There is a tutorial for this on the android developer website . Link is given below

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

There is also a very good video by Slidenerd explaining the InterFragment Communication. This is the easiest to understand and best one on the web.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyyGP_d0Ia8

Comment: Although this doesn't solve the problem completely, it gave me some clues on how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to use static fields to exchange information between activities and fragments. They have a lifecycle and, if the user rotates the screen or sends the app to background and the process is destroyed, your static variable value will no longer be available. This is the way to share information between fragments:

#### In FragmentA:

```
FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("position", position);
fragmentB.setArguments(args);
// Do your FragmentTransaction here.
```

#### In FragmentB:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.album, container, false);
    position = getArguments().getInt("position", 0);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return v;
}
```

Comment: I think he already has the B fragment created because he mentioned the ViewPager. Not sure tho

Comment: i, myself , currently stuck on it, what if Fragment is already created and we are coming from activity or fragment back to the created fragment, then how to tell the fragment hey there is change in your bundle, because we already have got bundle checked null or not in onCreate of Fragment when it was first created, i think methods like  @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);      
    } method will be useful

Comment: In this case you can declare a public method in the fragment and call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to have a interface implemented in your activity. And on each fragment onAttach function, get the interface. That way you have the temporal data in the activity and get it in the other fragment:

Interface :

```
public interface MyFragmentListener {
        int getSavedInt();
        void saveInt(int a);
    }
```

Your Activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragmentListener{
```

private int mInt;

```
 @Override public int getSavedInt(){return mInt;};

 @Override public void saveInt(int a){this.mInt = a;};

}
```

Your Fragment:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment{
 private MyFragmentListener mListener;

@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (mListener==null)
            if (context instanceof MyFragmentListener) {
                mListener = (MyFragmentListener) context;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement MyFragmentListener");
            }
    }


public void saveInt(int a){
if (mListener!=null)mListener.saveInt(a);
}

public int getInt(){
if (mListener!=null)return mListener.getSavedInt();
else return -1;
}


}
```